# how to mock/unit test downloads from amazon s3?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, amazon-s3, moq, awss3transferutility

I am new to unit testing/moq and was wondering how this could be done. I have a function that downloads a file from s3 to local. How can I mock this so that it doesn't actually use transferUtility to download anything from s3?

```
bool downloadFileFromS3(string localPathToSave, string filenameToDownloadAs, string bucketName, string objectKey)
{
    try
    {
        string accessKey = "xxx";
        string secretKey = "xxx";
        // do stuff before
        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(accessKey, secretKey);
        transferUtility.Download( Path.Combine(localPathToSave, filenameToDownloadAs), bucketName, objectKey );
        // do stuff after
        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I've created the mock but I don't know how to use it for testing the function that I wrote.

```
[Test]
public void testDownloadFromS3()
{
    string filePath = null;
    string bucketName = null;
    string key = null;

    Mock<Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility> mock = new Mock<Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility>();
    //mock.Setup(x => x.Download(filePath, bucketName, key)).Verifiable();
    //Mock.Verify();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TTransferUtility.html) the `TransferUtility` class implements the `ITransferUtility` interface.

If you need to test your `downloadFileFromS3` then your code **should depend on abstraction, not on concretions** as the [SOLID's DIP](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401769/depend-on-abstractions-not-on-concretions-what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-this-t) says.

```
private readonly ITransferUtility transferUtility; //should be set via constructor injection

bool downloadFileFromS3(string localPathToSave, string filenameToDownloadAs, string bucketName, string objectKey)
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff before

        transferUtility.Download( Path.Combine(localPathToSave, filenameToDownloadAs), bucketName, objectKey );

        // do stuff after
        return true;
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Because the `Download` [method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MTransferUtilityDownloadStringStringString.html) does not return anything all you need to do is to setup verifyability in case of happy path

```
[Test]
public void testDownloadFromS3_HappyPath()
{
    //Arrange
    const string localPathToSave = "C:/tmp/";
    const string filenameToDownloadAs = "test.txt";
    const string bucketName = "x";
    const string objectKey = "y";

    Mock<Amazon.S3.Transfer.ITransferUtility> transferUtilMock = new Mock<Amazon.S3.Transfer.ITransferUtility>();
    transferUtilMock
        .Setup(util => util.Download(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Verifiable();

    var sut = new ClassThatContainsTheDownloadFileFromS3(transferUtilMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = sut.downloadFileFromS3(localPathToSave, filenameToDownloadAs, bucketName, objectKey);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
    transferUtilMock.Verify(util => util.Download(
            It.Is<string>(filePath => string.Equals(filePath, localPathToSave +filenameToDownloadAs, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
            It.Is<string>(bucket => string.Equals(bucket, bucketName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
            It.Is<string>(key => string.Equals(key, objectKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
        Times.Once);
}
```

- We have set up the mock to accept any parameters ([It.IsAny](https://documentation.help/Moq/3CF54A74.htm))
- We have passed the mock instance's `Object` property to the class which contains the `downloadFileFromS3`
- I've used a name sut, which refers to [System Under Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test)
- We have used [It.Is](https://documentation.help/Moq/5976987C.htm) to verify that the `Download` method has been called in the way we expect
- We also [pass](https://documentation.help/Moq/B5B9BE8D.htm) a `Times.Once` to the `Verify` to make sure that the `Download` has been called exactly once.

---

This is how you can test the unhappy path:

```
[Test]
public void testDownloadFromS3_UnhappyPath()
{
    //Arrange
    const string localPathToSave = "C:/tmp/";
    const string filenameToDownloadAs = "test.txt";
    const string bucketName = "x";
    const string objectKey = "y";

    Mock<Amazon.S3.Transfer.ITransferUtility> transferUtilMock = new Mock<Amazon.S3.Transfer.ITransferUtility>();
    transferUtilMock
        .Setup(util => util.Download(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Throws<System.IO.IOException>();;

    var sut = new ClassThatContainsTheDownloadFileFromS3(transferUtilMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = sut.downloadFileFromS3(localPathToSave, filenameToDownloadAs, bucketName, objectKey);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
    transferUtilMock.Verify(util => util.Download(
            It.Is<string>(filePath => string.Equals(filePath, localPathToSave +filenameToDownloadAs, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
            It.Is<string>(bucket => string.Equals(bucket, bucketName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
            It.Is<string>(key => string.Equals(key, objectKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)),
        Times.Once);
}
```

- As you can see we have replaced the `Verifiable` call to `Throws` to throw exception whenever it is called
- I've also replaced the `Assert.IsTrue` to `Assert.IsFalse`

  - I've assumed that in case of exception `// stuff` returns `false`

Comment: Jus curious, does injecting IAmazonS3 also inject ITransferUtility or do you have to explicitly add it when configuring services?

Comment: @NickCipollina I think you should inject both if you need both of them

Comment: @PeterCsala can you show a sample code or git reference to your code where the injection would happen?

Comment: @VolleyballPlayer I've used constructor injection to pass the dependency (and its mock in case of unit testing): `var sut = new ClassThatContainsTheDownloadFileFromS3(transferUtilMock.Object)`. Or if I misunderstood your question could you please rephrase it?